# why there is error when set function in function's arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, darkmode

I want to set function in function's arguments like this:

```
export const Mode = (mode, setMode) => {

  mode == "dark" ? setMode("light") : setMode("dark")

}
```

and result was setMode is not a funtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");
  const toggleMode = (currentMode) => {
  if (currentMode === "dark") {
    setMode("light");
  } else {
    setMode("dark");
  }
}
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current mode is: {mode}</p>
      <button onClick={() => toggleMode(mode)}>Toggle Mode</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Explain your code ?

Comment: this code allows a user to switch between a 'dark' mode and a 'light' mode by clicking a button. The state change causes the component to re-render, updating the displayed mode on the screen.

Comment: mehdi if you need the code flow, trace and process I would explain it.

Comment: I just want to clarify the code you provided

Comment: @CodeForest code only answers are frowned upon. Take the time to explain what you have done, how it addresses the OP's question, and provide links to relevant resources when appropriate.